# Xcode 8 symbol not found linking sqlite3

Tags: xcode, google-analytics, sqlite, cocoapods, sqlcipher

I have an project in witch I use 2 pods, a private one that uses SQLCipher, and Google/Analytics that uses the systems sqlite3 (-l"sqlite3").

When I build my project with Xcode 7, everything works correctly, but when I build with Xcode 8 app crashes when trying to open the sqlite db with the following reason:

```
dlopen(/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, 0x00000001)
dlopen(/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib) ==> 0x1feec4f0
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_key
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/524A1D1F-CC6A-4F7C-B86F-CC65EAF17BD5/MyApp.app/MyApp
Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
```

Tested:

```
|         | iOS 8 | iOS 9 | iOS 10 |
| Xcode 7 |  OK   |  OK   |   OK   |
| Xcode 8 | CRASH | CRASH |    *   |

* app didn't crash but could not open db
```

What did Xcode 8 change? (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html)
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355893/implicit-declaration-of-function-sqlite3-key) appears to indicate that `sqlite3_key()` isn't included in the iOS version of sqlite3.  Also can you turn off the lazy loading of this library?

Comment: @Droppy how would you suggest I turn off lazy loading?

Comment: @Daniel I'm facing similar issue, Could you please suggest your solution !

Comment: @Droppy sqlite3_key() was working before with X-code 7 and iOS-9. After upgrade to X-code 8 and iOS-10 this started to create issue. Do you have any suggestion !!

Comment: @Daniel Any solutions you got for this issue? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @ParthBhatt I haven't found a solution. 
I did a hack, in creating my own Podspec for GoogleAnalytics - https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAnalytics and i've removed the sqlite3 dependency from it. Until now GA seems to work ok, but...

Answer (score 2):

If use pod import,  you can add post_install to modify OTHER_LDFLAGS, remove iOS system sqlite3 link flag l"sqlite3".

post_install do |installer|

```
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    puts "#{target.name}"    
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        puts xcconfig_path

        build_settings = Hash[*File.read(xcconfig_path).lines.map{|x| x.split(/\s*=\s*/, 2)}.flatten]

        if build_settings['OTHER_LDFLAGS']
            other_ldflags = build_settings['OTHER_LDFLAGS']

            puts other_ldflags

            if other_ldflags.include? '-l"sqlite3"'

                puts "find -l sqlite3"

                index = other_ldflags.index('-l"sqlite3"')
                length = '-l"sqlite3"'.length
                first_path = other_ldflags[0,index]
                last_path = other_ldflags[index+length..-1]
                exclude_ldflags = first_path + last_path

                puts exclude_ldflags

                build_settings['OTHER_LDFLAGS'] = exclude_ldflags
            end

            # write build_settings dictionary to xcconfig
            File.open(xcconfig_path, "w")
            build_settings.each do |key,value|
                File.open(xcconfig_path, "a") {|file| file.puts "#{key} = #{value}"}
            end
        end
    end
end
```

end

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, simultaneously using pods dependent on sqlite3 and SQLCipher isn't really a supported scenario with SQLCipher. You might check out this article containing guidance for using [SQLCipher with XCode 8](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/important-advisory-sqlcipher-with-xcode-8-and-new-sdks/1688) for reference, but what you are trying to do is high risk.

Comment: Stephen, I'm facing similar issue mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40263384/2624806), Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The problem in the post you linked to is that PRAGMA key= or sqlite3_key must be called each time the database is opened.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using sqlCipher and I got this problem `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_key` too. What I do is to add `-all_load` flag to project `Build Settings` -> `Other Linker Flags`, then all works fine. Hope this maybe help to someone. :)