# Reading for Encrypted DB not working for iOS 10

Tags: ios, encryption, sqlcipher

I'm working on an `iOS` application. `Encryption` & `Decryption` to read & write was working till `iOS 9`. But after upgrade to `iOS 10` it started to giving issue with following message that **"file is encrypted or is not a database".**

For `DB encryption` I'm using following code:

```
sqlite3 *db1;
if (sqlite3_open([[self.databaseURL path] UTF8String], &db1) == SQLITE_OK) {
const char* key = [@"strong" UTF8String];
sqlite3_key(db1, key, (int)strlen(key));

   if (sqlite3_exec(db1, (const char*) "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
      NSLog(@"Password is correct, or a new database has been initialized");
   } else {
      NSLog(@"Incorrect password!");
   }
  sqlite3_close(db1);
}
```

& it's working perfectly fine.

For opening and reading operation I'm using following code:

```
-(void)openDB
{
    NSString *docsDir;
    docsDir = [self getDirectoryPath];
    aPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SQLITE_DEMO.sqlite"];
    dbpath = [aPath UTF8String];
}
```

Reading:

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDBNew) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT  FROM USER"];

            const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
            char *err;

            int check = sqlite3_exec(contactDBNew, query_stmt, NULL, NULL, &err);

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDBNew, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            { 
                 // Successfully executed.
         } else {
              // Error in execution.
        }
  }
```

Here it get failed while reading **prepared statement** with following error message: "file is encrypted or is not a database".

Please suggest what I'm missing !!

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run PRAGMA key= or use sqlite3_key after every database open. In fact, it is best to open the database once at the start of your application, then close it at the end. It is very expensive to repeatedly open and close the database due to key derivation.

Comment: Thanks I did that. About to open DB everytime, that's true But what about issue if we have to perform multiple parallel read & write operation.

Comment: If you need to perform concurrent operations you should probably open multiple connections, and then serialize requests across those connections. Be aware that SQLCipher (like SQLite) does not allow for concurrent writes. If you are doing a lot of concurrent reads interleaved with writes, you may be interested in using WAL journal mode.